# Running two separate macros from 2 columns on the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to run 2 separate emails from 2 columns in the worksheet.

I have one email pattern for the column P and the other one for column Q

Unfortunately the code below doesn't collaborate with my idea

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("P:Q")) Is Nothing Then

   If Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("P")) Is Nothing Then

   Call EmailRequest
   Else
   Call EmailApproval
   End If
   End If
   End Sub
```

I am getting the following error:
Run-time error 1004

**Method 'Range of objects' Worksheet failed.**

How could I run 2 separate macros from 2 separate columns?

Comment: `"P"` is not a valid range address. Don't confuse `Target` and `ActiveCell`.

Comment: Change `ActiveCell` to `Target`. What's the expected output if selection crosses both Col P and Q (eg. P4:Q4)?

Comment: I would like separate email to populate on col P and separate for col Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls try.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("Q")) Is Nothing Then
        Call EmailRequest
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("P")) Is Nothing Then
        Call EmailApproval
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd bet that `EmailRequest` and `EmailApproval` rely on `ActiveCell` and need refactored with a `Range` parameter. That'll be the next question :-)

Comment: @BigBen Maybe, hope OP clarify the detail in the next qestion.